# Do you need to stratify / match sample for ANCOVA comparisons?

Tags: anova, matching

I have data about body image and weight change behaviours from $N = 397$ adolescent boys that we collected in 2000.  Age ranged from $13.5$ years to $18.67$ years and the mean age was $15.92~ [SD= 1.02]$.

We recently conducted another round of data collection in the same schools (plus additional schools that have a similar socioeconomic profile), using the same questionnaire, and we wish to compare body image and weight change behaviours between 2000 and 2012. As there were no year seven students in the initial cohort, the year 7 students were removed from the 2012 cohort.

We therefore have $n = 892$ participants in the 2012 cohort.  Age in this group ranges from $12.33-21.08$ years and the mean age was $15.09~ [SD=1.26]$. ANOVA indicated that there was still a significant difference between the age of the participants in the two waves of data collection $F(1,1281)= 135.91,~ p <.000$. Body image and weight change behaviours are closely linked to age.

My questions:

- Is there a problem comparing data from groups with these sample sizes ($397$ vs. $892$) using ANCOVA?
- Is ANCOVA enough to limit the impact of age on analyses? or should I match the sample for age by selecting at random from each age group in the recent data?